# Prove classic version of Jensens Inequality from the modern version of Jensens Inequality. Are they equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Classis version of Jensens Inequality:

Let $I \in \mathbb R$ be an interval and $\phi: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a convex function.

Let $n \in \mathbb N$, $\ell_1, \ldots, \ell_n > 0$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in I$.

Then $$\phi(\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i x_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i}) \le \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i \phi(x_i) }{\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i}$$.

I want to prove the classic version of Jensens inequality from the modern version used in measure theory.

I notice that in the case $n=2$ we have a convex combination and the result follows by considering $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i x_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i}$ (correct me if I'm wrong).

However, I've trouble continue from here. Should I proceed by induction, if so how ?

Also is the classic version and the modern version of Jensens Inequality equivalent ? (they imply each other, why ?)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** consider a random variable with distribution
$$
P(X = x_i) = \frac{l_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n l_j}
$$

---

In such a case, the Jensen inequality writes
\begin{align}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n l_i \phi(x_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^n l_j} &=
\sum_{i=1}^n P(X = x_i) \phi(x_i) \\&=  E\phi(X) \\&\ge
\phi \left(E(X)\right) 
= \phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^n P(X = x_i) x_i\right)
\\&= \phi\left(  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nl_ix_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n l_j} \right)
\end{align}

Comment: That's not a hint, but a full solution (you could put it in spoiler field, though).

Comment: yes, there is first a Hint. then after the line, the solution;